# PowerBI join table and calculation

Tags: powerbi, match, calculation

I have two tables:
Table 1

```
Year Name Score
2010 A    1000
2011 A    1200
2012 A    1200
2013 A    1300
2010 B    1100
2011 B    1500
2012 B    1300
2013 B    1600
```

Table 2

```
Year Factor
2010 3.57
2011 4.21
2012 6.11
2013 2.15
```

I would like to do this: match two tables, as long as Year in Table 1 match Year in Table 2, divide the score by the factor, e.g. for `A` in `2010, 1000/3.57`; for `B` in `2010,1100/3.57`

How to revise the following code?

```
adjusted score  = 
VAR
filter (all('Table 1'[Year]), 'Table 1'[Year]='Table 2'[Year])
RETURN
DIVIDE ('Table 1' [Score], 'Table 2'[Factor')
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: what is - "adjusted score"? is it a measure? or column?

Comment: it is just the name of the measure. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a **measure**, you can try this below code-

```
adjusted score = 

VAR current_row_year = MIN('Table 1'[Year])
VAR current_row_Score = MIN('Table 1'[Score])

VAR factor =
CALCULATE(
    MAX('Table 2'[Factor'),
    filter (
        all('Table 2'), 
        'Table 2'[Year]= current_row_year
    )
) 

RETURN DIVIDE (current_row_Score, factor)
```

Code for a **Custom Column** is as below-

```
adjusted score = 

VAR current_row_year = 'Table 1'[Year]
VAR current_row_Score = 'Table 1'[Score]

VAR factor =
CALCULATE(
    MAX('Table 2'[Factor'),
    filter (
        all('Table 2'), 
        'Table 2'[Year]= current_row_year
    )
) 

RETURN DIVIDE (current_row_Score, factor)
```

> **You can also do the same using Transformation using Power query. In that case you have to just merge your table 1 and 2 using Year and then after Expanding the table, you will have Factor in each row for the Year. You can then just add a new custom column with - Score/Factor**